# POS Terminal device's main target

Tags: credit-card

Please let me know one thing what I still confuse.

Most of the e-commerce web sites provide buying and selling products by just typing credit card or bank account information.

So, I wonder that If this upper procedure is correct, 
why we need POS Terminal Devices to make payment.
 Some say that there is some security issue to look up.

If so let me know these security issue more detail. And Why we need POS Terminal Devices.

Then, Is POS terminal device talk only to specific bank or multiple banks?

Answer (score 0):

At a physical point of sale, you expect the customers to present the card they want to pay with. If they just had to memorise a card number it would be wide open to fraud.

POS terminal devices also add additional security in a number of ways. They typically read the chip on the card, and verify the users PIN, then make a secure connection to perform authorization/settlement. It should prevent a rogue POS operator from capturing any of those details, and also hugely simplifies the integration for the POS software developer.

POS terminal devices can be bank specific, or can be tied to a payment gateway.